# Python (discord.py): New line(enter) after specific words in a loop

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.8

I am currently working on an aviation weather Discord bot where the user can request the specific weather of an airport. So for example, when you will type in: `!metar KJFK` it should return the METAR (Meteorological Aerodrome Report) and TAF (Terminal Aerodrome Forecast).
At this moment, I got it working but it returns one-liners. This is the result I get when I enter the ICAO station of Amsterdam-Schiphol:

Input: `!METAR EHAM`
Output:

```
METAR: EHAM 071755Z 27008KT 230V300 9999 FEW030 19/11 Q1016 NOSIG
TAF: TAF EHAM 071707Z 0718/0824 26010KT 9999 FEW030 BECMG 0719/0722 19003KT BECMG 0812/0815 27008KT PROB30 TEMPO 0812/0816 7000 -SHRA FEW025TCU BECMG 0821/0824 23003KT
```

How it should be:

```
EHAM 071755Z 27008KT 230V300 9999 FEW030 19/11 Q1016 NOSIG

TAF EHAM 071707Z 0718/0824 26010KT 9999 FEW030
  BECMG 0719/0722 19003KT
  BECMG 0812/0815 27008KT
  PROB30
  TEMPO 0812/0816 7000 -SHRA FEW025TCU
  BECMG 0821/0824 23003KT
```

So after every 'BECMG' and 'TEMPO' it starts at a new line. I have been trying for hours on how to solve this issue. I am still learning so I was hoping that someone is able to help me out with this question.

The code I have at the moment:

```
@client.command(aliases=['METAR', 'TAF', 'taf'])
async def metar(ctx, *, metar_station):
    #METAR
    url_metar = 'https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/current/metars.cache.csv'
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url_metar)
    lines = [l.decode('utf-8') for l in response.readlines()]
    cr = csv.reader(lines)
    for row in cr:
        if row[0].startswith(metar_station):
            result_metar = row[0]

    #TAF
    url_taf = 'https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/current/tafs.cache.csv'
    response_taf = urllib.request.urlopen(url_taf)
    lines_taf = [l.decode('utf-8') for l in response_taf.readlines()]
    cr_taf = csv.reader(lines_taf)

    for row_taf in cr_taf:
        if row_taf[0].startswith(str('TAF ') + metar_station):
            result_taf = row_taf[0]


            
    await ctx.send(f'**METAR**: {result_metar}\n**TAF**: {result_taf}')
```

I really hope someone is able to help me out with this matter. I have been working on this already for hours and I am really getting stuck here.

Thank you so much in advance for your help and support.

All the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of methods to do this, but for easy and better understanding purpose I used the [str.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to replace the specific word with adding"`\n`"before them.

```
result_taf = result_taf.replace("BECMG","\nBECMG").replace("TEMPO","\nTEMPO").replace("PROB30","\nPROB30")
```

So The Final Code Wil be: `(little edited)`

```
@client.command(aliases=['METAR', 'TAF', 'taf'])
async def metar(ctx, *, metar_station):
    #METAR
    response = urlopen('https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/current/metars.cache.csv')
    lines = [l.decode('utf-8') for l in response.readlines()]
    cr = csv.reader(lines)
    result_metar = [row[0] for row in cr if row[0].startswith(metar_station)][0]

    #TAF
    response_taf = urlopen('https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/current/tafs.cache.csv')
    lines_taf = [l.decode('utf-8') for l in response_taf.readlines()]
    cr_taf = csv.reader(lines_taf)

    result_taf = [row[0] for row in cr_taf if row[0].startswith(f"TAF {metar_station}")][0]
    result_taf = result_taf.replace("BECMG","\nBECMG").replace("TEMPO","\nTEMPO").replace("PROB30","\nPROB30")
    await ctx.send(f'**METAR**: {result_metar}\n**TAF**: {result_taf}')
```

**Output**:

```
EHAM 080255Z 09001KT CAVOK 13/11 Q1018 NOSIG
TAF EHAM 072308Z 0800/0906 VRB03KT 9999 FEW030
BECMG 0806/0809 24007KT
PROB30
TEMPO 0812/0816 7000 -SHRA FEW025TCU
BECMG 0818/0821 VRB03KT PROB40 0822/0905 4500 BR
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out. I have been thinking about the str.replace() function but I wasn't sure how to use it in this case. Now that you have assigned it to a variable it actually makes sense. Now I understand how to use it and I am confident that this will help me in the future with other projects.
Again thank you for your help! It is much appreciated!